# Error TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am using Django Rest Auth with Django All Auth.

When I hit an endpoint `/rest-auth/password/reset/` (POST method with an email address) I receive an email includes a URL to reset a password.

And then I cleck the URL, I have an error like below:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /password-reset/confirm/MzY/5l0-c1042120be1e07140e64/
TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'
```

In general, after clicking that URL the screen should transit to a browser of `/rest-auth/password/reset/confirm/`.

But in my case, it doesn't work like that...

How can I solve this error?

---

Here are the codes:

project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),

    path('account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', TemplateView.as_view(),
         name="account_confirm_email"),

    path('account-confirm-email/', include('allauth.urls')),

    re_path(
        r'^password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        TemplateView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_confirm'),
]
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_auth.serializers import PasswordResetSerializer


class CustomPasswordResetSerializer(PasswordResetSerializer):

    def get_email_options(self):
        print("check override")

        return {
            'domain_override': 'localhost:8000',
            'email_template_name': 'account/email/password_reset_key_message.txt',
        }
```

password_reset_key_message.txt

```
A password reset has been requested.
Click the link below to continue.

{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

settings.py

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER': 'path.to.serializers.CustomPasswordResetSerializer',
}
```

---

python: 3.7.5

Django:2.2.2

django-allauth:0.41.0

django-rest-auth:0.9.5

djangorestframework:3.12.1

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about those additional library. You can make your own custom password_reset `serializers` and `views` like below, make sure you provide JWT token based authentication while you reset the password from user.

`serializers.py`:

```
class ResetPasswordSerializer(Serializer):
    new_password      = serializers.CharField(error_messages={'required':' new_password key is required', 'blank':'new password is required'})
    confirm_password  = serializers.CharField(error_messages={'required':' confirm_password key is required', 'blank':'confirm password is required'})
```

`views.py`:

```
class ForgotPasswordResetAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes=[JSONWebTokenAuthentication,]
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        data = request.data
        user = request.user
        print(user)
        serializer = ResetPasswordSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            new_password = serializer.data.get("new_password")
            confirm_password = serializer.data.get("confirm_password")
            if new_password == confirm_password:
                print('ok')
                user.set_password(new_password)
                user.save()
                return Response({'success':"true",'message':'Your password have been reset successfully'},status=200)
            return Response({'success':"False",'message':'Both password fields must be same'},status=400)                
        return Response(serializer.errors , status=400)
```